# The wx.App object must be created first! Part 2

Tags: python, wxpython

I saw another post with this problem but the solution did not work for me. The two halves of this code work separately but not together. **(I couldn't get the indent code option in this post to work so I recreated it here....so at this point maybe there is more than one mistake...)

```
import wx
import numpy as np
import os
import numpy


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    wildcard = "Python source (*.py)|*.py|" \
            "Compiled Python (*.pyc)|*.pyc|" \
            "All files (*.*)|*.*"
    dlg = wx.MessageDialog(None, "Run program?",
                      'Power over DeltaT',
                      wx.YES_NO | wx.ICON_QUESTION)
    retCode = dlg.ShowModal()
    if (retCode == wx.ID_YES):
        dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, "File", os.getcwd(), "", wildcard, wx.OPEN)
        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            x, y, z = np.loadtxt(dialog.GetPath(), dtype=float, delimiter=',',
                                 skiprows=2,usecols=(6, 18, 19), unpack=True)
            dialog.Destroy()
            print x
            f = (z-y) / (x+.01)
            average=numpy.sum(f)/f.shape[0]
            print average
dlg.Destroy()

class StaticTextFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Average Watts per Delta T', size=(400, 300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "The average :", (100, 100))
        x=(13.21)
        stra = str(x)

        text = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, stra, (200, 100))
        font = wx.Font(18, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.ITALIC, wx.NORMAL)
        text.SetFont(font)

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = StaticTextFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay... So the main problem you're probably only getting when you double-click on the .py file (i.e., run it as main); that is assuming that `dlg.Destroy()` is properly indented.

So, the your problem is that wx.Python only wants one app running at a time and you are technically calling two: once inside the main and once outside.

Delete `app = wx.PySimpleApp()` and `app.MainLoop()` from the end of the file and put the frame calls at the end of `if __name__=='__main__'`

Though I haven't actually coded with it yet, my advice (for future reference) would be to transition to Kivy: http://kivy.org/#home

It looks awesome.

Comment: Also, remove the double import of numpy.

Comment: Where should I move  class StaticTextFrame(wx.Frame):

Comment: Actually, what are you trying to do? It is not at all clear from your question or the code.